# Jquery Mobiles, pages and image linking

Tags: jquery, image, url, cordova, mobile

I'm developing an app and I just started developing in jQuery Mobile. But now I seem to be stuck with a (I think) very simple problem.

My structure looks like this:

```
index.html  
|  
pages  
|--login.html  
|--otherpage.html  
|  
images  
|  
|--logo.png
```

The problem is accessing `logo.png` relatively. I use the image in `index.html` and `login.html`.
I'd like to access the image by the same URL in both pages.

I've already tried a few things, like setting a < base > tag. But nothing seems to work :(
Can someone please help me to get on the right track!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same URL since your html files are in different folders

In index.html it'll be

```
<img src="images/logo.png" />
```

In login.html

```
<img src="../images/logo.png" />
```